# Search query to find articles on website with certain tags

Tags: php, laravel, october-cms

I have the following search query to find pages on my website where I'd like to make as much as possible use of existing functionalities to determine relationship names and to hardcore the least as possible.

I have the following relationships:

```
Richpage
   - belongsTo
       - Domain
       - SearchResult
           - belongsToMany
               - Tags
                   - belongsTo
                        - TagType
       - IndexedArticle
            - hasMany
                - IndexedArticleWord
                    - belongsTo
                        IndexedWord
                            - belongsTo
                                 - Language
```

In this query I'm searching for articles that match the words that were provided in the search query. A search query is split up into an array of words that is fed into the below query.

Then the results are in the query also matched against the tag criteria.

For example, if you have a tag type theme with the tags:

- nature
- cities
- ocean

and a tag type region with the tags:

- east
- west
- south
- north

and someone checked the tags nature and ocean and east then all the results that contain east and either nature or ocean should be returned.

At the end I need to return the total results count, the results and the tags of all the results before the query is limited to 20 results.

I ended up with this code to make the query work as the specifications I wrote above. I'd like some pointers on how to improve this or to have possible pitfalls pointed out.

This query will run for now on SQL Server, but I'd love to have this database agnostic, so any pointers on how to make this further database independent would be most appreciated.

```php
public function performSearchQuery(array $words, $page = 0, $results_per_page = 20) 
    {


        $richpage = new RichPage();
        $richpage_table = $richpage->getTable();
        $richpage_qualified_key_name = $richpage_table . '.'. $richpage->getKeyName();

        $richpage_to_domain_relation = $richpage->domain();
        $richpage_to_domain_foreign_key = $richpage_to_domain_relation->getQualifiedForeignKey();

        $richpage_to_search_result_relation = $richpage->search_result_display();
        $richpage_to_search_result_foreign_key = $richpage_to_search_result_relation->getQualifiedForeignKey();


        $richpage_to_indexed_article_relation = $richpage->indexed_article();
        $indexed_article_model = $richpage_to_indexed_article_relation->getRelated();
        $indexed_article_table = $indexed_article_model->getTable();

        $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_relation = $indexed_article_model->indexed_words();
        $indexed_article_words_model = $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_relation->getRelated();        
        $indexed_article_words_table = $indexed_article_words_model->getTable();
        $indexed_article_words_qualified_key_name = $indexed_article_words_table.'.'.$indexed_article_words_model->getKeyName();

        $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_relation = $indexed_article_words_model->indexed_word();
        $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_foreign_key = $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_relation->getQualifiedForeignKey();
        $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_other_key = $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_relation->getQualifiedOtherKeyName();

        $indexed_words_model = $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_relation->getRelated();
        $indexed_words_table = $indexed_words_model->getTable();

        $indexed_article_to_richpage_relation = $indexed_article_model->richpage();
        $indexed_article_to_richpage_other_key = $indexed_article_to_richpage_relation->getQualifiedOtherKeyName();
        $indexed_article_to_richpage_foreign_key = $indexed_article_to_richpage_relation->getQualifiedForeignKey();

        $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_other_key = $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_relation->getQualifiedParentKeyName();
        $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_foreign_key = $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_relation->getForeignKey();

        $search_result_display_model = $richpage->search_result_display()->getRelated();
        $tags_model = $search_result_display_model->tags()->getRelated();
        $tags_key_name = $tags_model->getKeyName();
        $tags_table = $tags_model->getTable();
        $tags_qualified_key_name = $tags_table.'.'.$tags_key_name;

        $tags_to_tag_types_relation = $tags_model->tag_type();

        $tag_type_model =$tags_to_tag_types_relation->getRelated();
        $tag_type_table_name = $tag_type_model->getTable();
        $tag_type_key_name = $tag_type_model->getKeyName();

        $tags_to_tag_types_other_key = $tags_to_tag_types_relation->getQualifiedOtherKeyName();
        $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key = $tags_to_tag_types_relation->getQualifiedForeignKey();

        /**
         * Gather all the tag types with it's underlying tags that are in the post request.
         * These are needed for limiting the search results to these tags and tag types
         */
        $tag_types_with_tags = null;
        if($tag_keys = post($this->getName('searchfilter'))) {
            $tag_types_with_tags = PageTagType::
            whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tag_keys, $tags_key_name) {
                $query->whereIn($tags_key_name, $tag_keys);
            })
            ->with(['tags' => function($query) use ($tag_keys, $tags_key_name) {
                $query->whereIn($tags_key_name, $tag_keys);
            }])
            ->get();

        }


        $query = $richpage->newQuery()

        ->select([
            $richpage_qualified_key_name,
            "$richpage_table.url",
            $richpage_to_domain_foreign_key,
            $richpage_to_search_result_foreign_key,
            DB::raw("sum($indexed_article_words_table.word_weight_in_page) as word_weight")
        ])

        ->leftJoin($indexed_article_table, 
                    $indexed_article_to_richpage_other_key,
                    '=',
                    $indexed_article_to_richpage_foreign_key)

        ->leftJoin($indexed_article_words_table, 
                    function($join) use ($indexed_article_model, 
                                         $indexed_article_words_table, 
                                         $words, 
                                         $indexed_article_table, 
                                         $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_other_key,
                                         $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_foreign_key,
                                         $indexed_words_table,
                                         $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_foreign_key,
                                         $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_other_key,
                                         $indexed_article_words_qualified_key_name
                        ) {
                        $join->on($indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_other_key,
                                    '=', 
                                  $indexed_article_to_indexed_article_words_foreign_key);

                        $bindings = str_repeat('?,',count($words));
                        $bindings = substr($bindings, 0, -1);
                        $join->where(
                            DB::raw("(select count(distinct $indexed_words_table.word)
                                        from $indexed_words_table
                                        where $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_other_key = $indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_foreign_key
                                        and $indexed_words_table.word in ($bindings))"), '>', 0);
                        $join->bindings = (array_merge($words, $join->bindings));
        })

        ->groupBy($richpage_qualified_key_name,
                    "$richpage_table.url",
                    $richpage_to_domain_foreign_key,
                    $richpage_to_search_result_foreign_key)

        ->havingRaw("sum($indexed_article_words_table.word_weight_in_page) > 0")

        ->havingRaw("count(distinct $indexed_article_words_qualified_key_name) = " . count($words))

        ->whereHas('domain', function($query) {
            $domain = Config::getDomainModel();
            if(Config::isDevelopDomain()) {
                $domain = Domain::find(1);
            }

            $query->where($domain->getKeyName(), '=', $domain->getKey());
        })

        ->where('exclude_from_indexing', '!=', true)

        ->whereHas('search_result_display', function($query) use (
                                                                    $tag_types_with_tags, 
                                                                    $tag_keys,
                                                                    $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key,
                                                                    $tags_to_tag_types_other_key,
                                                                    $tag_type_table_name,
                                                                    $tag_type_key_name,
                                                                    $tags_key_name,
                                                                    $tags_qualified_key_name
            ) {
            $query->whereNotNull('title');

            if($tag_types_with_tags) {
                /**
                 * Special query, to allow multiple selections of tags within the same tag type
                 * whilst requiring that every tag type is there at least once.
                 */
                $query->whereHas('tags', function($query) use(
                                                                $tag_types_with_tags,
                                                                $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key,
                                                                $tags_to_tag_types_other_key,
                                                                $tag_type_table_name,
                                                                $tag_type_key_name,
                                                                $tags_key_name,
                                                                $tags_qualified_key_name
                    ) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw("count(distinct $tag_type_key_name)"));

                    $query->leftJoin($tag_type_table_name,
                        $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key,
                        '=',
                        $tags_to_tag_types_other_key);

                    $query->where(function($query) use (
                                                            $tag_types_with_tags, 
                                                            $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key,
                                                            $tags_key_name,  
                                                            $tags_qualified_key_name
                        ) {

                        foreach($tag_types_with_tags as $tag_type) {

                            $query->orWhere(function($query) use (
                                                                    $tag_type, 
                                                                    $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key,
                                                                    $tags_key_name,
                                                                    $tags_qualified_key_name
                                ) {

                                $query->where($tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key, $tag_type->getKey());
                                $tags_list = $tag_type->tags->lists($tags_key_name);
                                $query->whereIn($tags_qualified_key_name, $tags_list);

                            });

                        }
                });           
                }, '=', $tag_types_with_tags->count());

            }

        })

        ->whereHas('indexed_article',function($query) use($words) {

            $query->whereHas('indexed_words', function($query) use($words) {

                $query->where('word_weight_in_page', '>', 10);
                $query->whereHas('indexed_word', function($query) use($words) {
                    $query->likeWord($words, Config::$language);
                });

            });

        })
        ;

        /** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823915/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-laravel-query-builder */
        $count = DB::table(DB::raw("({$query->toSql()}) as sub"))
                        ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())
                        ->count();

        /** this actually works 0_o **/                
        $richpage->table = DB::raw("({$query->toSql()}) as sub");

        $newQuery = $richpage->newQuery()
                    ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery());

        $tags = null;

        $query->with([
                'search_result_display.tags' => function($query) use (
                                                                        &$tags, 
                                                                        $tags_key_name, 
                                                                        $tags_qualified_key_name
                    ) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw($tags_qualified_key_name));
                    $tags = array_unique($query->get()->lists($tags_key_name));
                }
        ])->get();

        $tags = PageTag::whereIn($tags_key_name, $tags)
            ->with('tag_type')
            ->select("$tags_table.*")

            ->leftJoin($tag_type_table_name,
                   $tags_to_tag_types_foreign_key,'=',$tags_to_tag_types_other_key)
            ->orderBy("$tag_type_table_name.sort_order",'asc')
            ->orderBy("$tags_table.sort_order",'asc')
        ->get();

        $newQuery->with([
                        'search_result_display.image',
                        'search_result_display.tags'
        ]);

        $newQuery->orderBy('sub.word_weight', 'desc');

        $newQuery->skip($results_per_page * $page)
                 ->take($results_per_page);

        $values =  $newQuery->get();

        return [$count, $values, $tags];
    }
```

Comment: These variable names make my wrists hurt more then they normal do `$indexed_article_words_to_indexed_words_relation`  I'm all about verbose variable names, but to a limit.  And if you use a variable once, and it comes from a class, you can probably just dump it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix actually that variable that you mentioned gets used 3 times. I used to have the direct functions calls everywhere but it made the code more messy and harder to read to see what was in relation to what.